# SQLite Sort by Source Column

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

In my SQLite database, I have a query that selects records where a string is present in one of several columns - i.e with the following

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| String | StringString |

I have the following query:

```
WHERE Column1 LIKE 'String' OR Column2 LIKE '%String%'
```

How can I make it so that the results are ordered based on which column they matched with? I.e. put items that matched from Column1 before items that were matched with Column2, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite Boolean expressions like `Column1 LIKE '%String%'` are evaluated as `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`, so you can sort by these expressions descending:

```
ORDER BY Column1 LIKE '%String%' DESC, 
         Column2 LIKE '%String%' DESC,
         .............................
```